# Need animation to other ID on the page, jsfiddle included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

When I click a link to an element ID, I want it to animate, like the first ID fade out and the new one that's being scrolled to fades in.

OR

I want to animate scroll to the other one. I've looked around on here and on other sites, including google searches, and I haven't found anything that works with my code. I understand I'll need jquery etc, everything I've tried hasn't worked so I've removed all the JS.

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Also if there's a simpler solution to having the content in the middle with no scroll bar so each section loads faster but stays in the middle I'd love to know. I'm pretty new to all this it's really confusing. And I haven't got much of a clue about JavaScript yet.

Thank you.

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family:tahoma;
    overflow:hidden;
}

body {
    background: url(http://www.visionpharmacy.org.uk/assets/img/main/22.jpg) no-repeat;
    height:100vh;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper {
    width:960px;
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    height:100vh;
    z-index:1;
}

.wrapper > #welcome, #contact {
    background:rgba(250,250,250,0.8);
    padding:40px;
    margin-top:15vh;
    height:80vh;
}

header {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    height:10vh;
    background:white;
    z-index:2;
    }

header > h1 {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:2em;
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
    line-height:70px;
    font-weight:600;
    color:black;
    float:left;
}

nav {
  float:right;
  line-height:10vh;
  padding:0 20px 0 0;
}

a[name="backtotop"] {
    font-size:1em;
    color:black;
}

a[name="backtotop"]:hover {
    color:lightseagreen;
    transition:0.3s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.320, 1);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Company Name</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="language" content="English">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>

            <h1>Company Name</h1>
<nav>
            <a href="#first">Home</a> - <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</nav>
        </header>

        <main>
            <div id="first" class="wrapper">
                <div id="welcome">
                    testing 1, 2

                    <a name="backtotop" href="#">Back to top</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="contact">
                    More testing?

                    <a name="backtotop" href="#">Back to top</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </main>



    </body>
</html>
```

JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5nwudmhc/

Comment: so. you want when you click on Contact to scroll down to the contact section ? or you want both of your sections ( home and contact ) to be in the same place an simply change between them ( like some sort of tabs ) ?

Comment: Yeah I want it to scroll to the contact section and end up in the same position as the first ID is.

OR

If that's not possible, then like a tab system yes! :) Where the first element would fade out and the next (contact) would fade in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Add smooth scrolling to all links
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {

        // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            // Prevent default anchor click behavior
            event.preventDefault();

            // Store hash
            var hash = this.hash;

            // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
            // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 800, function(){

           // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
               window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        } // End if
    });
});
```

Then you should add the `#contact` (or any `#IDhere` for that matter) to the link you want the user to click.

And add `id="contact"` (or any `id="IDhere"` for that matter) to the element you want to scroll to.

**EDIT:**

okay, so the not scrolling part is due to the fact that the overflow is hidden (`overflow: hidden;`), when you remove that, it'll work, but the background will also move up, so in the `body` element in the CSS you need to add `background-attachment: fixed;` to the `body` element aswell, now the problem is that the content at the top of the page is not readable because of the navbar, the content is still there. But I guess you can fix that yourself. I'll provide a final snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/64vmo586/

Comment: this uses the JQuery libary, but I see you are already including that so I didn't add it to my answer

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The time it takes to show is working, if I click it, it will appear 0.8s later, however it doesn't scroll, just appears. But this is closest so far!

Comment: I wasn't at my home computer (am now, just came back from work), I'll now try to perfect my answer

Comment: Amazing answer, just what I needed. Thanks very much Luuk!

Answer (score 0):

i think something like this would work to animate the scrolling:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

    var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

    if( target.length ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var scrollhere = target.offset().top;

        $('html, body').animate({                   
            scrollTop: scrollhere
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Then you need to have the same href as the div ID where you want it to scroll, for instance:

```
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
```

will scroll to

```
<div id="contact">
```

If you want to change the speed of the animation, you can change that number just and the end of the function. in the example i have set to 1000ms ( equals to 1s)

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: Hey, thanks. I tried it but nothing would work unfortunately :(